# Alter Sections Using Jquery Layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-layout

I am using jquery layout for the first time.

I have it working using the defaults:

```
$('body').layout(
{
    applyDefaultStyles: true 

});
```

but I want to disable the closing of the sections

```
$('body').layout(
{
     center: 
     {
         closable: false
     },
     north:
     {
         closable: false
     },
     west:
     {
         closable: false         
     },
     south:
     {
         closable: false
     } 

});
```

I just have basic html now:

```
<div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-south">South</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: how do I make the sections non-closeable? When I add the sections it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you link to the specific layout plugin you're using?

Comment: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `defaults` section.

Check out this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/CUQVX/

When I first tried your code out, nothing worked, because I didn't have the defaults section with `applyDefaultStyles`.

Once I put that in, all was well.